# Django url dispatcher - wrong function

Tags: python, django, django-urls

i am new to Django and i have some problem with Django URL dispatcher.

I have "prometfire" project and "homepage" app.

My goal is to connect this paths to their view functions:

127.0.0.1:8000 --> "homepage_view"

127.0.0.1:8000/welcome --> "welcome_view"

"homepage_view" works fine, but when i go to 127.0.0.1:8000/welcome i have same result as in "homepage_view", instead of "welcome_view" result.

Am i missing something?

Django 1.5
Python 2.7

```
#urls.py in prometfire

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^welcome/', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)



#urls.py in homepage app

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('homepage.views',
    url(r'^$', 'homepage_view'),
    url(r'^welcome/', 'welcome_view'),
)



#views.py in homepage app

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def homepage_view(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage.html',
                             {'name': 'bob'}
    )

def welcome_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Welcome')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are including your homepage urls twice. Remove the second entry

```
url(r'^welcome/', include('homepage.urls')),
```

This is explained in the docs on [including other url confs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

> Whenever Django encounters include() (django.conf.urls.include()), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

In your case, the `'welcome/'` is removed from the url, which leaves `''`, which is matched by the url pattern for the homepage.

Comment: Thank you, i removed this line and $-symbol from the r'^$' and everything works fine! Your link to the docs was useful.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I hadn't noticed that you would have to remove the `$` from the other include. Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it never enters the second condition for the app, it verifies the condition at the url `root conf, welcome/`, and after that goes directly to `^$` in the app. A solution would be remove the `welcome/` from the url `root`.
The first welcome definition is redundant and is causing the "bug".